# How to retrive data from database between two time ranges?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I want to filter my data by date-range as well as the time range.
I am done with date-range but not getting a solution for the time.

I want to retrieve data between two-time range. How could I do that?

here is my code for date range:

1) Ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  
           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"filter.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#order_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>
```

2) SQL Query :

```
if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  {  
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "data");  
  $output = '';  
  $query = "  
       SELECT * FROM date_filter  
       WHERE date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  
  ";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  $output .= '  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                 <th width="30%">Customer Name</th>   
                 <th width="12%"> Date</th>  
                 <th width="12%"> Time</th>
            </tr>  
  ';  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td>'. $row["id"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["customer_name"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["date"] .'</td>  
                      <td>'. $row["time"] .'</td>  
                 </tr>  
            ';  
       }  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td colspan="5">No data Found</td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '</table>';  
  echo $output;   }  ?>
```

Help me with Time filtering. To Retrieve data from Database.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL

Comment: And **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Anyway it sounds like you are wanting to add times to the existing dates you are inputting? Is that right? if so then it would make sense to use a date-time picker in the UI instead of a plain datepicker. Maybe check out some of these: https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-date-time-picker.html

Comment: @ADyson Yes exactly. I want to get data from database using time likewise I have done for the date range

Comment: ok. Well, then, does my suggestion make sense to you?